# Custom D3.js donut chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image: Donut]

I want to create a donut like above using d3.js but i am unable to make one. I am able to make a normal donut using d3.js.

Please anyone have any idea on how to make this donut using d3.js?

Comment: who told you to make that chart not normal donut chart

Comment: i have a requirement to make a chart like this one and not a normal one.

Comment: In this there are 4 partitions or there could be more?

Comment: @Cyril: No, number of partitions are fixed. It will always be 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you confirmed there will be 4 set of data

So 4 arcs with different inner and outer radius.

```
var biggestarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 80)
    .innerRadius(radius - 10);

var bigarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 30)
    .innerRadius(radius - 60);

var smallarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 50);

var biggerarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 20)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);
```

Data will be in this format.

```
data = [{
    "label": "Biggest",
        "percent": 25 //percent to be shown for Biggest arc
}, {
    "label": "Bigger",
    "percent": 10 //percent to be shown for Bigger arc
}, {
    "label": "Big",
    "percent": 65 //percent to be shown for Big arc
}, {
    "label": "Small",
    "percent": 30 //percent to be shown for Small arc
}]
```

Choose the path arc as per the label:

```
g.append("path")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
    console.log(d)
    if (d.data.label == "Biggest") {
        return biggestarc(d);

    } else if (d.data.label == "Bigger") {
        return biggerarc(d);

    } else if (d.data.label == "Big") {
        return bigarc(d);

    } else {
        console.log("target")
        return smallarc(d);
    }
})
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WSWAgeZZGzs1yLaGIjBQ?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks You very much.

Comment: What is the use of this labelarc?

Comment: No need delete it I was trying to put text label around it.